# Is there a way to remove the stock Google apps without rooting your phone

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, moto-x

Hi I'm using Moto X style and most the space consuming apps are stock Google one which I basically don't use at all. Is there a way to remove them without rooting the device. I know it's an hard ask but I'm just taking a chance here ?

Comment: Is this the stock rom you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Not a chance, sorry. You cannot remove pre-installed apps (System apps) without *write* access to `/system` – which you won't have without `su` ([rooting](/questions/tagged/rooting)). All you can do is deactivating *parts* if the Google Apps – you probably cannot even deactivate them all, as some will show up as "protected" (aka "I am too important").

Best way to really get rid of all of them is to flash a custom ROM, which usually comes without GApps.